# MFC: Overriding a bitmap path in RC file in satellite DLL

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a primary executable that uses the following RC files:

- `main.rc`
- `bitmaps.rc`

The `main.rc` will `#include bitmaps.rc`.

I would like the bitmaps (and other resources) to be swap-able at run time, so I decided to use the DLL approach and swap the resource using `AfxSetResourceHandle`.

My current approach:
In the satellite DLL project, it's RC file will simply do an `#include main.rc` to first grab all the resources from the main executable.  Then, I replace specific bitmaps (only a handful that requires changing) using the following:

```
#undef IDB_ICON
IDB_ICON    BITMAP    "..\\newIcon.bmp"

#undef IDB_ABOUT
IDB_ABOUT   BITMAP    "..\\newAbout.bmp"
```

The `#undef` makes it compile without spewing out a "duplicate resource" error.  However, the substitution doesn't work at run time.

The only way I could get it to work is to replicate `bitmaps.rc` as `bitmapsSatellite.rc` in the satellite project, and then make the handful of path swaps. And of course, `main.rc` was tweaked to only include one bitmap rc file, depending on the project.

My desired approach would be cleaner and self explanatory.  Is there a way to make it work, perhaps using something other than `#undef`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to undefine the resource IDs.

Resources with the same Id may exist with different language id in one resource file.

To separate them it is easy to compile the RC file with a command line setting  that predfines `AFX_RESOURCE_DLL`.

When `AFX_RESOURCE_DLL` is defined for the resource compiler it only includes resources for a language that is also defined on the command line like `AFX_TARG_ENU` or `AFX_TARG_DEU`.

For resources that may always be included in the satelaite DLL I use `AFX_TARG_NEUD` (Neutral resource).

So you may have all resources in one file, or you may have resources spitted into more than one RC file. You may include all needed resource files into one compile process via `#include` statement and you my select the target language you need via the command line define.